# C++: Strange header error showing up

Tags: c++, xcode, opencl

```
#ifndef _MY_OPENCLPLATFORM_
#define _MY_OPENCLPLATFORM_

#include "OpenCL.h"

namespace my
{

    class OpenCLPlatform
    {
        cl_platform_id mplatformID;

        cl_uint mnumDevices;

        std::vector<OpenCLDevice> mdevices; // OpenCLDevice was not declared in this scope

    public:
        OpenCLPlatform(cl_platform_id platformID);

        void getDevices();

        void printInfo();

        cl_platform_id& getPlatformID();
    };
}

#endif

#ifndef _MY_OPENCLDEVICE_
#define _MY_OPENCLDEVICE_
#include "OpenCL.h"

namespace my
{
    class OpenCLDevice
    {
        cl_device_id mdeviceID;

    public:
        OpenCLDevice(cl_device_id device);

        void printInfo();

        void printDeviceType(cl_device_type deviceType);
    };
}

#endif

#ifndef _MY_OPENCL_
#define _MY_OPENCL_
#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(MACOSX)
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h> // This works only for XCODE compiler
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Exception.h"
#include "OpenCLDevice.h"
#include "OpenCLPlatform.h"

namespace my {

    class OpenCLDevice;
    class OpenCLPlatform;
    class OpenCL;


    class OpenCL
    {
        cl_uint mnumPlatforms;
        std::vector<OpenCLPlatform> mplatforms;

        void getPlatforms();
    public:

        OpenCL();
        ~OpenCL();

        void quickSetup();

        void printPlatformVersions();
    };
}

#endif
```

Does the the ordering "class OpenCLDevice; class OpenCLPlatform; class OpenCL;" matter? Sometimes, header files depend on each other which can lead to "hard to follow" or convoluted inclusions...Do you have a "one way" technique to deal with convoluted inclusions that you use all the time?

Edit:

I changed the code to match my real problem. If you look at the code above, the compiler is saying that 'OpenCLDevice was not declared in this scope'.

Edit:

I finally got the code to work, and this is what I did:
1. add #include "OpenCLDevice.h"in OpenCLPlatform.h
2. compile
3. remove #include "OpenCLDevice.h"in OpenCLPlatform.h
4. compile
It works now!

Edit:

I cleaned the project and removed all dependencies, and I'm getting the same errors again.

Edit:

I think compiler did something to the code. It may have chose to not include libraries that aren't used in the header and source file, but are used in other headers and source codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are including classa.h and classb.h where both classes are (presumably) defined, you shouldn't even need the forward declaration.

However, if you did not include them, then no, order of the declarations wouldn't matter. As long as as a class is forward declared before it is used you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential issues:

Your `#include "OpenCL.h"` may not include the file you expect (yours), but instead some system file.

Forward declarations can't be used in your case. It works only when you have pointers or references to class instances. Your `vector<OpenCLPlatform>` requires the class declaration (i.e. inclusion of the corresponding header).